# Function reference in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, lambda

I have following declarations:

```
abstract class Foo<K, V>(
    val bar: (K) -> V
)

fun lotsOfFun() = 42
```

Is it possible to pass a no-argument function (e.g. `lotsOfFun`) in the `bar` place so that it fits the type? Something like this:

```
class Derived: Foo<???, Int>(::lotsOfFun)
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared `bar` to have the signature`(K) -> V`.

`lotsOfFun` has the signature `() -> V` so the short answer is no. You could define `lotsOfFun` as:

```
fun <K> lotsOfFun(ignored : K) = 42


fun main() {
    class Derived: Foo<String, Int>(::lotsOfFun)
    Derived().bar("").also { println(it) } // 42
}
```

that would be legal but smelly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Any?`, the super type of every type. This provides the most flexibility if you combine it with contravariance.

```
// K is contravariant and V covariant
abstract class Foo<in K, out V>(
    val bar: (K) -> V
)

fun lotsOfFun() = 42

class Derived: Foo<Any?, Int>({ lotsOfFun() })

// if you *really* like using a function reference:
// fun <T, R> constant(f: () -> R): (T) -> R = { f() }
// class Derived: Foo<Any?, Int>(constant(::lotsOfFun))
```

With this, an instance of `Derived` is compatible with `Foo<K, Int>` where `K` can be any type:

```
val foo1: Foo<String, Int> = Derived() // OK
val foo2: Foo<Int?, Int> = Derived() // OK
val foo3: Foo<IntArray, Int> = Derived() // OK
```

If you can't make `Foo` contravariant, because `K` is used in an "output position" (e.g. return type) somewhere else in `Foo`, then decide what it should be based on what you want to output.

Making `Derived` generic might also be suitable:

```
class Derived<K>: Foo<K, Int>({ lotsOfFun() })
```